# How to show the non-selected options in a select form, after a previous form is submitted

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form where im asking for name, surname, phone cellphone and at the end user has to check one or more options in a checkbox and then clicks submit.

After that in the "thank you page" i want to show the exact form but this time to show only the non-checked checkboxes.
Reason for this is that i want to say "We highly recommend you check all the options for better results, you can do so by simply clicking the submit button below"

And then below that i want to present the form as i said, but the remaining checkboxes (the oens that were not checked before) would be only the NON-checked options in the previous page. Makes sense?

Ive tried hard with php if states and switches but still cant get the result i want, it seems i have to define "false statements" in a way im not cabable of doing it.

Should i use php or jquery?

Can anyone help me? Im kinda lost.
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

(EDIT: Post-reworded after question edited)

Ok, my suggested solution is still similar to the one before you reworded the question.  You have a list of checkboxes?  I'd start by putting the names of these checkboxes in to an array:

```
$checkboxes = Array("checkbox1" => 0, "checkbox2" => 0, "checkbox3" => 0);
```

Render your list of checkboxes using this array for consistency (this prevents you adding a checkbox not in the list, etceteras).  Render only those whose value is '0'.

When you submit your form and are processing the `$_POST`, you can set to '1' any checkbox that has been ticked.  Re-render the checkboxes (it will only do those with a value of 0)

EDIT: Sorry it took so long, am a bit busy and my php is kind of rusty.  I apologise to every PHP programmer that reads this, it is quick and dirty!!"

```
<?php
function renderCheckboxes($checkBoxes)
{
    foreach($checkBoxes as $field => $value)
    {
        if($value == 0)
            echo("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"$field\" />".
                 "<label for\"=$value\">$field</label><br/>");
    }
}

// initialise possibibilites
$array = Array("Name" => 0, 
               "Tel" => 0, 
               "Address1" => 0, 
               "Address2" => 0, 
               "Town" => 0, 
               "Postcode" => 0, 
               "Country" => 0);

// process form here
$posting = count($_POST) > 0;
if($posting) // submitting?
{
    foreach($_POST as $field => $value)
        $array[$field] = 1;
}
echo("<html>".
        "<body>".
            "<form name=\"frmTest\" id=\"frmTest\" method=\"post\" action=\"test.php\">");
if($posting)
    echo("We highly recommend you select the following:<br/>");
renderCheckboxes($array);
echo("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" />".
            "</form>".
        "</body>".
      "</html>");

?>
```

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand what you are saying.

Comment: Its just that the Checkbox doesnt have all the checkboxes checked.
PD: SORRY, i meant checkboxes in my post, NOT select, sorry again, ill edit now.

Comment: it does makes sense but still cant get it work, im a php noob though.

Comment: What, specifically, are you have trouble with?  What doesn't work?

Comment: i store the checkboxes in an array as u said, but then on the second page what would be the exact code to: present the array and THEN removefromarray those that were ticked and THEN to "echo" that result in the checkbox ? thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Ok, example incoming, give me a sec.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and time, ill test this and report back